# Looping through an Array from Hashmap Data in Java

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, hashmap

I have `XML` file that I downloaded from a web service, the issue that I have is that I cannot get it display the data correctly outside of the loop.

The `XML` format is set up like:

```
<section>
    <outage>
        <dummydata>test</dummydata>
   </outage>
    <outage>
        <dummydata>test2</dummydata>
   </outage>
</section>
<section>
   <outage>
    <dummydata>test3</dummydata>
   <outage>
</section>
```

Note some sections can have more that one outage. As you can see below the counts are right but the one outage is from the 4.

```
01-24 22:54:49.176: I/System.out(1924): Outage Count per sect 1
01-24 22:54:49.176: I/System.out(1924): Outage Count per sect 1
01-24 22:54:49.176: I/System.out(1924): Outage Count per sect 1
01-24 22:54:49.176: I/System.out(1924): Outage Count per sect 1
01-24 22:54:49.176: I/System.out(1924): Outage Count per sect 4
01-24 22:54:49.186: I/System.out(1924): Outage Count per sect 1
01-24 22:54:49.186: I/System.out(1924): Outage Count per sect 1
01-24 22:54:49.196: I/System.out(1924): Outages : 763674
```

and this is the code that is doing all the work

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrPolygons.size(); j++) {

     if (isPointInPolygon(point, arrPolygons.get(j).getPoints())) {
      for (int outageInfo = 0; outageInfo < nodeList.getLength(); outageInfo++) {
            outageData = new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
             Node ouageInfoNode = nodeList.item(outageInfo);

              Element ouageInfoElement = (Element) ouageInfoNode;
              NodeList ouageInfoList = ouageInfoElement.getElementsByTagName("Outage");
              System.out.println("Outage Count per sect "+ouageInfoList.getLength());
                 for (int outages = 0; outages < ouageInfoList.getLength(); outages++) {
                     Node outageNode = ouageInfoList.item(outages);
                     Element outageDataElement = (Element) outageNode;
                     NodeList outageDataList =outageDataElement.getElementsByTagName("outagenum");   

                     outageDataElement = (Element) outageDataList.item(0);
                     outageDataList = outageDataElement.getChildNodes();

                     outagenum = ((Node) outageDataList.item(0))
                            .getNodeValue();

                    //This is what I want to loop 
                      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                      map.put("outagenum", outagenum);
                    outageData.add(outages, map);                        
                    } 

                }
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inside " + arrPolygons.get(j).getId()+" "+ outageData.get(j), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  System.out.println("Outages : " + outageData.get(0));

              }
           }

         }
    }
```

my outcome should look like

```
Index 0 - {test,test2}
Index 1 - {test3}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong within this loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int outageInfo = 0; outageInfo < nodeList.getLength(); outageInfo++) {
            outageData = new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

should

```
         outageData = new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 for (int outageInfo = 0; outageInfo < nodeList.getLength(); outageInfo++) {
```

Comment: I did that now it is index 0-2, the sample about is how I need it to display index 0-1 with zero having multiple values. thoughts?